# Prove subgroups of cyclic groups are cyclic without division algorithm, rings, homomorphisms or $\gcd$ of infinite numbers?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, cyclic-groups

I have found a lot of proofs on this site, on proofwiki and elsewhere. I thought of my own which was unlike all I found except for 1 proof (I have linked it below.) and was wondering if I could get anywhere with it.

> Let $G$ be a cyclic group generated by $x$. Let $G=\langle x \rangle$. Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. If $H$ is trivial, we're done. Otherwise, $\exists n \in \mathbb Z$ s.t. $x^n \in H, n \ne 0$. By definition of a subgroup, $\langle x^n \rangle$ is a subgroup of $H$. If $\langle x^n \rangle \ne H$, then consider $x^{n_1} \in H \setminus \langle x^n \rangle$ to get $\langle x^{n_1} \rangle$ is a subgroup of $H$. If $\gcd({n_1},n)=1$, then $H=G$. Otherwise, $\langle x^{\gcd({n_1},n)} \rangle$ is a subgroup of $H$. If this isn't the whole of $H$, then consider $x^{n_2} \in H \setminus \langle x^{\gcd({n_1},n)} \rangle$ and so on.

**I think this process is finite** for some reason like we need only consider positive integers less than some positive integer. All we need is 2 relatively prime exponents to get all of $G$, so it seems unlikely that the process is infinite.

1. A thought just came to mind that if it's finite, then it's probably due to the division algorithm? Does anyone know a way to prove finiteness without the division algorithm?
2. If this process is potentially infinite, then why?

The most similar proof I found online was in http://brianbi.ca/artin/2.4 where he lets $H=\{x^i | i \in S\}$ and then considers $d=\gcd_{i \in S}(i)$.

I really feel I'm missing something simple to say somehow

$$\langle x^n \rangle \subseteq H \subseteq \langle x \rangle$$

implies, if $H$ is a subgroup of $\langle x \rangle$, that $H = \langle x^n \rangle$ else some $H = \langle x^m \rangle$ where

$$\langle x^n \rangle \subseteq \langle x^m \rangle \subseteq H \subseteq \langle x \rangle$$

3. Another idea I had was to create a bijection between $\mathbb Z$ and $\langle x \rangle$, but does anyone know a way to go about this without homomorphisms?

Note: The division algorithm is used as part of some proof of some fact used above, so there's no avoiding division algorithm. My intention is to avoid using division algorithm again.

Comment: I think the best way is to prove $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z_n}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ are all the cyclic groups up to isomorphism, and then it is enough to work only with these groups and prove their subgroups are cyclic. Why do you want to do it without homomorphisms?

Comment: @Mark In my textbook, this exercise is given before homomorphisms. Is there a way to do this with bijections but without homomorphisms? Similar to isomorphisms but without the homomorphism property. I also want to understand if my thinking is going somewhere in particular whether or not the process is finite. I think I will learn something from whether or not the process is finite. :)

Comment: Yes, you can prove a subgroup of an infinite cyclic group is cyclic without proving it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$. But the proof I know still uses the division algorithm. It is different from the proof you showed though.

Comment: @Mark Wait, I mean to not re-use the division algorithm because the division algorithm is used in the proof of at least 1 fact used by me or Brian Bi. Thank you anyway if you can't think of any!

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the division algorithm?

Comment: @Christopher I mean to not re-use the division algorithm because the division algorithm is used in the proof of at least 1 fact used by me or Brian Bi. So, there's no avoiding that it was already used. I want to avoid using it again. It seems like reinventing the wheel to me. Division algorithm is already used to prove the subgroups of $\mathbb Z$ are $\mathbb Z n $. I think this should lead us somewhere. I think it does with isomorphisms, but in this case, I would like to know if this is possible to do with just the "iso" and not the "morphism" (bijection). Additionally (continued)

Comment: (continued) I want to understand whether or not my process is finite, and why.

Comment: Your process is definitely finite. The sequence $\gcd(n,n_1),\gcd(n,n_1,n_2),\gcd(n,n_1,n_2,n_3),\ldots$ is a strictly decreasing sequence of positive integers. By the well-ordering principle, the process must stop. But know this, using $\gcd$ means that you are already using division algorithm implicitly.

Comment: @Batominovski Do you mean [Convergence of a monotone sequence of real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Convergence_of_a_monotone_sequence_of_real_numbers) ? Thank you!

Comment: No, I mean this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_infinite_descent.  There is no sequence of positive integers that has the infinite decent property.

Answer (score 2):

One can actually completely avoid invoking the division algorithm by referring to the well-ordering of natural numbers:

- Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G=\langle x\rangle$. If $H$ contains only the neutral element, we are done.
- Otherwise, let $n$ denote the smallest positive integer for which $x^n\in H$. This is well-defined since $H$ contains at least one non-neutral element and positive integers are well-ordered.
- Let $H'=\langle x^n\rangle$ be the cyclic subgroup generated by $x^n$. If $H=H'$, we are done.
- Otherwise, let $m$ denote the smallest positive integer for which $x^m\in H\ \backslash\ H'$. Again, $m$ is well-defined because the set is non-empty and positive integers are well-ordered.

We are almost done now:

- $1\leq n<m$, since $n$ was the lowest non-trivial exponent in the whole $H$, while $m$ was the lowest in a subset of it and was explicitly prevented from being equal to $n$.
- We have $x^m\in H$ and $x^n\in H$, which implies $x^m\left(x^{-1}\right)^n=x^{m-n}\in H$.
- $x^{m-n}$ must belong to $H'$, for otherwise it would contradict the choice of $m$ choice of $m$ as the minimal exponent within $H\ \backslash\ H'$ (since $(m-n)<m$).
- But since $x^{m-n}\in H'$ and $x^n\in H'$, we must also have $x^{(m-n)+n}=x^m\in H'$; a contradiction with our choice of $m$ as exponent of a $H\ \backslash\ H'$ element.

Of course, the well-ordering principle can also be used to prove that the division algorithm works for non-negative integers first and arrive at the same conclusion by applying it to compute $\gcd$s.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to mention that the fact that every subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ is cyclic implies the existence of GCDs, so in some way, asking for proof of "Every subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic" and the existence of GCDs, from elementary principles, are equivalenc problems:

Let $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$. Consider the subgroup $H=m\mathbb{Z}+n\mathbb{Z}$ of $\mathbb{Z}$. Since it is cyclic, it is of the form $H=d\mathbb{Z}$ for some $d\in\mathbb{Z}$. Since $H\neq 0$ then $d\neq 0$. Changing $d$ by $-d$ if necessary we can assume $d>0$.

Since $m\mathbb{Z}\subseteq d\mathbb{Z}$, then $d|m$, and similarly $d|n$. if $p$ is another divisor of both $m$ and $n$, then $m\mathbb{Z}\subseteq p\mathbb{Z}$, and $n\mathbb{Z}\subseteq p\mathbb{Z}$, so $d\mathbb{Z}=m\mathbb{Z}+n\mathbb{Z}\subseteq p\mathbb{Z}$, which means that $p$ divides $d$. This proves that $d$ is the GCD of $m$ and $n$.